# Excel 2010 line chart; limiting data points to fewer than the max

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, charts

In Excel 2010, how do I limit the number of data points on a line graph to the latest (or last) 4 data?
I update the spreadsheet often, but only the latest data is graphed and reported.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you update the sheet containing the source data.
The range used for the `Series` changes upon inserting/deleting cells (or rows, columns).

Say you have your data in columns, and you have a series defined by

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$6,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$6,1)
```

You may update your worksheet by:

1. Inserting cells above the range plotted (say, at row 2). Then the ranges of the series will shift downwards to

   ```
      =SERIES(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$4:$D$7,Sheet1!$C$4:$C$7,1)
   ```

   but they will not extend (I understand this is your target).
2. Inserting cells below the range (say, at row 8). Then the ranges will not change.
3. Inserting cells in the middle (say, at row 5). The ranges will extend downwards to

   ```
      =SERIES(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$4:$D$8,Sheet1!$C$4:$C$8,1)
   ```
4. Simply entering more data below row 7.

Case 1 works for you. Cases 2-4 are not ok (cases 2,4 are similar), and they could use VBA coding.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Updates are adding a row of data, some will show on the chart. Ranges include blank rows to keep from having to change the range each time an update is made.

Comment: Now, we have to hide all but the last 4 rows to keep the chart limited to 4 points. Each time we add a row, we must hide a row. Is there an easier way? Something more automatic? Perhaps Dynamic Range? Or a Slider bar?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still somewhat confusing. 
I’m guessing that you have data in `A1` through `A42`,
and you want to chart `A39`, `A40`, `A41`, and `A42` (the last four). 
Then, next week (or whenever) you will add a number in `A43`,
and then you will want to chart `A40`, `A41`, `A42`, and `A43`. 
I suggest that you set up a staging area in your workbook
that will automagically hold the last four values in static locations. 
Enter `=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER($A:$A),ROW($A:$A)))` into `B1` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
This will cause it to be treated as an *array formula*. 
It will display in the formula bar as `{=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER($A:$A),ROW($A:$A)))}`,
with curly braces, and it will display in the cell as `42`,
the maximum row number for which there is data in Column `A`. 
Then set

- `B2` - `=INDEX($A:$A,$B$1-3)`
- `B3` - `=INDEX($A:$A,$B$1-2)`
- `B4` - `=INDEX($A:$A,$B$1-1)`
- `B5` - `=INDEX($A:$A,$B$1)`

Now `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, and `B5` will display the values of `A39`, `A40`, `A41`, and `A42`, respectively. 
When you add a number in `A43`, `B1` will change to `43` and `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, and `B5` will display the values of `A40`, `A41`, `A42`, and `A43`. 
So chart `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, and `B5`.

Note: this will capture the last four rows, counting backwards (i.e., up)
from the last one that has a number in it -- even if some of them are empty. 
For example, if `A40` is blank and you want to chart `A38`, `A39`, `A41`, and `A42`,
the above solution won’t work. 
That case can be handled; it’s just a little more complicated.